# Alfresco. How to show the form field by condition?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Good afternoon. There is a business process with many tasks. In one of the tasks there are two association fields (for simplicity, let's call their field 1 and field 2). As when opening this task, check the value in field 1 and, depending on its value, hide or show field 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the OOTB free marker (.ftl) file for your control. e.g. selectone.ftl located at

> alfresco-home\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\controls

then add JavaScript code to it to show/hide your fields.

Comment: Many thanks. then another question. Could you tell me how to set or remove the property of the "mandatory" of one field, depending on the value of the other field

Comment: You mean to say you want to make a field 'A' mandatory based on the value of the field 'B'. right? If that is the case then it is also possible in JavaScript.